# How to combine not disjoint sets in all possible ways?

Tags: algorithms

Let's say that I have a set of sets. 
Each of them composed by two or more subsets.

For example:

S = {S1, S2, S3}

S1 = [0,1,**2,3**] = {S11 = [0,1], S12 = [2,3]}

S2 = [**2,3**,**4,5**] = {S21 = [2,3], S22 = [4,5]}

S3 = [**4,5**,6,7] = {S31 = [4,5], S32 = [6,7]}

As you notice, the intersection between S1-S2 and S2-S3 is not empty.

I am implementing a program and I would like to generate these results:

1) S11 [0,1], S2 [2,3,4,5], S32 [6,7]

2) S1 [0,1,2,3], S3 [4,5,6,7]

I want every result to contain all numbers without any intersection allowed (if I can not accomplish that with the bigger sets, I can use their subsets).

Can you think of a clever algorithm to do this?

I feel like it is somehow a known problem, but as I am not a math expert, I do not know what to google for.

For now, I am implementing this with a brute force approach (I try all combinations), but it is not efficient.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is very closely related to the set packing problem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing ) which is known to be NP-complete (i.e. very hard, e.g. most likely exponential time to solve). Probably even in your formulation where you insist that the subsets you choose must cover the entire set, the problem is still hard, even if the total number of solutions is small. Thus, some kind of brute force is probably your only way to go. Depending on how you arrange your brute force search, you may be able to speed things up a bit but you're still probably facing exponential time in terms of the number of subsets you have.